# How can I make sure if the given curve is monotonic with respect to $x$ and $y$?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, parametric-functions, differentials

I have two functions $ f(x,y) $ and $ g(x,y) $ over the domains $ 1<x< 2$ and  $0<y<\pi$. I use `ContourPlot` to ses those values of $(x,y)$ for which $g(x,y)=0$ assuming that $f(x,y)>1$

```
f[x_, y_] :=  Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x];
g[x_, y_] := (3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x) +  Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/ x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x])^2];

ContourPlot[  g[x, y] == 0 , {x, 1,2}, {y, 0, Pi}, FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y},   f[x, y] > 1]]
```

I get this plot

[image]

**Question**

> Using `With[{y = Pi},   NSolve[g[x, y] == 0 && 15/10 < x < 16/10 && f[x, y] > 1, x]]`
> and as can be seen in the plot, we know that there is no solution at $y=\pi$. How can I make sure if, in this blue curve (i.e. those $(x,y)$ for which $g(x,y)=0$ and $f(x,y)>1$), by increasing $x$ (or $y$), the other variable $y$ (or $x$) increases as well? I ma not sure if MONOTONE is the correct word in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a implicit function `g[x,y]==0`,we can regard `y` as the function of `x` and according the calculus that
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}/\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}$$

We use `Contours->{0}` to draw the region which $\frac{dy}{dx}>0$ or $\frac{dy}{dx}<0$ under the condition $f(x,y)>1$ and we get only the red part $\frac{dy}{dx}>0$ mean that `y` is a increasing function which respect to `x`( so at the same time, `x` is a increasing function which respect to `y`)

```
f[x_, y_] = 
  Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x];
g[x_, y_] = (3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x) + 
   Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/
         x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x])^2];

dydx = ContourPlot[{-D[g[x, y], x]/D[g[x, y], y] // Evaluate}, {x, 1, 
    2}, {y, 0, π}, Contours -> {0}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, f[x, y] > 1], 
   ContourShading -> {Cyan, Red}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   MaxRecursion -> 2];
contour = 
  ContourPlot[{g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 0, π}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, f[x, y] > 1], PlotPoints -> 50, 
   ContourStyle -> Black];
Show[dydx, contour]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Then, is this reliable also for those values of  $y$ very close to $\pi$ which ContourPlot needs higher precision?     @cvgmt